# Mostrar el contenido de la opción seleccionada, no el value

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo este `<select> <option>` en php donde seleccionas a un usuario, *seleccionas otras opciones* y después haces clic en **guardar**. Es importante que el `value` exista para que pueda guardar en la tabla de myslq la id del usuario.

El problema es que cuando seleccionas una opción te muestra el número de la ID (o sea el `value`). La intención es que al seleccionar un usuario, veas el nombre del usuario que seleccionaste.

```
<option value='". $data['id_usuario'] ."'>" .$data['nombre'] ."</option>
```

Intente de agregar `label` pero no funciona. Es como que lo ignora por completo y te sigue mostrando el `value`

Tampoco puedo insertar el nombre en el `value` por que es un texto, se necesita guardar la ID.

Acá lo dejo la sección del select

```
  <datalist  name="usuarios" id="usuarios">
    <?php
    $link = conectar();
    $listausuarios = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id_usuarios, nombre
                                        FROM usuarios 
                                        ");

    while($data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($listausuarios))
    {
        echo "<option value='". $data['id_usuario'] ."'>" .$data['nombre'] ."</option>";
    }   
    ?>
  </datalist>
```

Comment: cuando te refieres a `La intención es que al seleccionar un usuario, veas el nombre del usuario que seleccionaste.` donde se tiene que ver esto??

Comment: En el frontend. ejemplo: Como cuando seleccionas un país y vez lo que seleccionaste del dropdown, no la id.

Comment: Realmente `datalist` no es un `select` ([mira esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29882539/5587982)). ¿Por qué en vez de `datalist` no usas un  `select` normal? Si tiene que ser con `datalist` sí o sí, puedes usar `data-value` en cada option.

Comment: Ahi lo cambie a `select` y muestra lo que esta en el campo, el problema era que con `datalist` puedo agregar un campo para buscar. Si se puede hacer con `datalist` mejor. Sino hay buscar alguna forma de poder buscar una opcion en un `select`.

Comment: https://select2.org/searching - Algo como esto podría ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Se puede lograr fácilmente con unos cuantos cambios:

- Crear un input oculto para guardar ID de usuario, en el ejemplo lo puse como texto para probar el funcionamiento; en tu proyecto solo cambia el tipo a `hidden` y elimina el atributo `disabled`
- Al campo se nombre le asigné ID para obtenerlo más fácilmente
- En la lista, en lugar de value, se asigna un [atributo de datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) para guardar ID de usuario, al no tener valor, el contenido se asignará al campo nombre

Finalmente, en *javascript* creas las variables necesarias y asignas el evento *INPUT* al campo nombre. Hay comentarios en el código para que sepas qué hace cada instrucción.

```js
// Campo para asignar ID
let idUsuario = document.querySelector('#idUsuario');
// Campo para seleccionar nombre
let usuario = document.querySelector('#usuario');
// Opciones de la lista
let opciones = document.querySelectorAll('#datalist option');
// Ejecutar cuando se hagan modificaciones en el campo de nombre
usuario.addEventListener('input', e => {
    // Poner ID en cero por defecto
    idUsuario.value = 0;
    // Recorrer opciones para validar nombre
    for(let i = 0; i < opciones.length; i++) {
        // Si el nombre tecleado es igual al de la opción
        if(usuario.value == opciones[i].innerText) {
            // Asignar ID y salir del ciclo
            idUsuario.value = opciones[i].dataset.id;
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="id_usuario" id="idUsuario" disabled>
<input list="datalist" name="nombre" id="usuario">
<datalist id="datalist">
  <option data-id="1">Juan</option>
  <option data-id="2">Paco</option>
  <option data-id="3">Pedro</option>
</datalist>
```